# Webview2 disable sleeping tabs programmatically

Tags: webview2

Im using Webview2 in a windows form C# App.
After some time of inactivity the site i'm connected, disconnect automatically and i think is due to "sleeping tabs" feature of edge browser.

["sleeping tabs" feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAQPk.png)

How can i disable "sleeping tabs" feature in Webview2 programmatically with C#?

Thanks